# file.read() on appengine returns junk characters

Tags: python, google-app-engine, file-io

I'm using the following code:

```
class Image(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, id):
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'fcimages/%s.png' % id)
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'image/png'
        print file(path,'rb').read()
```

And it works fine locally (i.e. returns the image), but when I use it on the live server I get junk. You can see the output here: http://1.ge0.co/fc/1.png

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

PS - I know this isn't the most robust code but it's only being used for my internal project, it's not built to scale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to fix it eventually, I think the problem was the combination of self.response and print. Here's the code that works:

```
class Image(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, id):
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'fcimages/%s.png' % id)
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "image/png"
        self.response.out.write(file(path, 'rb').read())
```

Comment: yes.  never use `print` in a webapp RequestHandler.  You'll print to stdout instead of to the response object, and what you printed will end up in the raw CGI response, usually hidden in the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Content-Type is not set correctly

```
Content-Length:72643
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Thu, 27 Jan 2011 13:01:57 GMT
Server:Google Frontend
```

This would explain why you see the contents of the file instead of the rendered image.

Comment: I changed line 4 in my original code to: print "Content-Type: image/png" and now I get a blank page instead of the junk code... Any further tips?